# mypy: Missing return statement when function does not return anything if condition failed

Tags: python, return, mypy

I have a function that has the following type definition:

```
def func_name(kw_details: list, val_details: list) -> Optional[Dict]:
    if condition:
        do something
        return dict_result
```

In case the condition fails, it doesn't return anything. So, I keep getting the error: `Missing return statement` from mypy.

What should the typing for the function look like, in order to accommodate my logic?

Comment: `func_name` will return `None` as default if the condition is false, so make it explicit?

Comment: @Guy Thanks. Don't know why I over-thought this.  Just adding `else: return None` does it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following in order to avoid the error from mypy.

```
def func_name(kw_details: list, val_details: list) -> Optional[Dict]:
    if condition:
        do something
        return dict_result
    return None
```